# WebService with Apache CXF and custom headers

Tags: java, cxf, spring-ws

I created a web service using [Apache cfx](http://cxf.apache.org/) and spring, it works, but I need that the response include this header

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Right now the response is like this.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:postEncuestaResponse xmlns:ns2="http://webservice.atomsfat.com/">
         <respuestaEncuesta>
            <dn>12315643154</dn>
            <encuestaPosted>true</encuestaPosted>
            <fecha>2009-09-30T16:32:33.163-05:00</fecha>
         </respuestaEncuesta>
      </ns2:postEncuestaResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

But should be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:postEncuestaResponse xmlns:ns2="http://webservice.atomsfat.com/">
         <respuestaEncuesta>
            <dn>12315643154</dn>
            <encuestaPosted>true</encuestaPosted>
            <fecha>2009-09-30T16:32:33.163-05:00</fecha>
         </respuestaEncuesta>
      </ns2:postEncuestaResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This is the configuration of the beans of spring that expose the service.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />

    <jaxws:endpoint
      id="encuestas"
      implementor="webservice.serviceImpl"
      address="/Encuestas" >
    </jaxws:endpoint>

</beans>
```

this is the interface

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public interface Encuestas {

    @WebResult(name= "respuestaEncuesta") 
    RespuestaEncuestaMsg postEncuesta (@WebParam(name = "encuestaMsg") EncuestaMsg message);

}
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I implement a Handler, first I downloaded the examples from CXF and modified the logging Handler, and it works.

The configuration of spring :

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />

    <jaxws:endpoint
        id="encuestas"
        implementor="com.webservice.EncuestasImpl"
        address="/Encuestas">
    <jaxws:handlers>
            <bean class="com.webservice.HeaderHandler"/>

        </jaxws:handlers> 

    </jaxws:endpoint>
```

And the code this is the code for the handler.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package com.webservice;

import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPHandler;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPMessageContext;

/*
 * This simple logical Handler will output the payload of incoming
 * and outgoing messages.
 */
public class HeaderHandler  implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

    private PrintStream out;

    public HeaderHandler() {
        setLogStream(System.out);
    }

    protected final void setLogStream(PrintStream ps) {
        out = ps;
    }

    public void init(Map c) {
        System.out.println("LoggingHandler : init() Called....");
    }

    public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
        return null;
    }

    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext smc) {
        System.out.println("LoggingHandler : handleMessage Called....");
        logToSystemOut(smc);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext smc) {
        System.out.println("LoggingHandler : handleFault Called....");
        logToSystemOut(smc);
        return true;
    }

    // nothing to clean up
    public void close(MessageContext messageContext) {
        System.out.println("LoggingHandler : close() Called....");
    }

    // nothing to clean up
    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println("LoggingHandler : destroy() Called....");
    }

    /*
     * Check the MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY in the context
     * to see if this is an outgoing or incoming message.
     * Write a brief message to the print stream and
     * output the message. The writeTo() method can throw
     * SOAPException or IOException
     */
    protected void logToSystemOut(SOAPMessageContext smc) {
        Boolean outboundProperty = (Boolean)
            smc.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);

        if (outboundProperty.booleanValue()) {
            out.println("\nOutbound message:");
        } else {
            out.println("\nInbound message:");
        }

        SOAPMessage message = smc.getMessage();




        try {
            message.setProperty(SOAPMessage.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION, "true");
            message.writeTo(out);
            out.println();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            out.println("Exception in handler: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: that in the try I use `MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY` like Justin suggested.

Comment: This will only show with in the handler as you are printing the output to "System.out". But once the handler finishes, CXF overwrites the response and final response wont have the XML declaration.

Answer (score 4):

Or use CXF build-in configuration capabilities.
Just add this IN your CXF Spring config :

```
<jaxws:properties>
    <entry key="org.apache.cxf.stax.force-start-document">
        <bean class="java.lang.Boolean">
            <constructor-arg value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </entry>
</jaxws:properties>
```

Comment: Adding endpoint.getProperties().put(StaxOutInterceptor.FORCE_START_DOCUMENT, Boolean.TRUE.toString()); to EndpointImpl does the same trick, but the prolog will be wrong, it. with single upperstrokes instead of double.

Comment: To clarify, it will add <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> instead of <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Answer (score 3):

Check the following

[How can I add soap headers to the request/response?](http://cxf.apache.org/faq.html#FAQ-HowcanIaddsoapheaderstotherequest%252Fresponse%253F)

[Adding JAX-WS handlers to web services](http://www.jroller.com/gmazza/entry/adding_jax_ws_handlers_to)

[Converting JAX-WS handlers to Apache CXF interceptors](http://www.jroller.com/gmazza/entry/apache_cxf_switching_between_jax)

then decide for one of the options and implement a handler/interceptor which adds what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Folowing the links provided by jitter, I went to http://cxf.apache.org/faq.html#FAQ-HowcanIaddsoapheaderstotherequest%252Fresponse%253F and found the following solution:

```
    // My object of the custom header
    AuthenticationHeader aut = new AuthenticationHeader();
    aut.setUserName("ws");
    aut.setPassword("ws123");

    IntegrationWS integration = new IntegrationWS();

    List<Header> headers = new ArrayList<Header>();
    Header dummyHeader;
    try {
        dummyHeader = new Header(new QName("http://www.company.com/ws/", "AuthenticationHeader"), auth, new JAXBDataBinding(AuthenticationHeader.class));
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
    headers.add(dummyHeader);

    IntegrationWSSoap soapPort = integration.getIntegrationWSSoap12();

    //client side:
    ((BindingProvider)soapPort).getRequestContext().put(Header.HEADER_LIST, headers);

    ArrayOfBrand arrayBrand = soapPort.syncBrands();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Apache CXF specific knowledge, but the jax-ws way to add the xml declaration seems to be to make a handler and use [SOAPMessage.setProperty()](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPMessage.html#setProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) to turn that feature on:

```
message.setProperty(SOAPMessage.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION, "true");
```

You should be able to add a jax-ws handler to your endpoint by adding a jaxws:handlers element in that spring config.